# pymongo, при подключении к монге выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
   import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from config import *
from table_create import tablecreate
import sqlite3
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient

connection = sqlite3.connect("server.db") 
cursor = connection.cursor()
tablecreate()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=disnake.Intents.all(), test_guilds=[guildID]) #Тут айди сервера.
client.remove_command('help')

cluster = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
client.cluster = cluster

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=disnake.Status.online)
    print(f"{client.user} запущен")
    
for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Адресс монги:

```
MONGO_URI: str = "mongodb+srv://***:****@cluster0.wbx8zhg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Вот сама ошибка:

```
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: All nameservers failed to answer the query _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.wbx8zhg.mongodb.net. IN SRV:
```

То есть код даже не запускается.
Но если убрать +srv в адресе монге, тогда код запустится но при попытке внести данные, отобразить,изменить выбывает ошибку.

Comment: [DNSChecker](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php?query=cluster0.wbx8zhg.mongodb.net&rtype=TXT&dns=google) finds it.  Does your DNS server return a TXT record?